# RSS feed only showing top 20 feeds of twitter account

Tags: twitter, rss

My account has over 450 tweets but when I try to fetch it's rss feed it's only giving me latest 20feeds. Is there any way to fetch all of tweets together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch up to 200 tweets on a single RSS feed.

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=rvn&count=200
```

200 is the API limit. But you can add a page number to get past 200:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=rvn&count=200&page=2
```

which will display tweets 201 to 401. Also, the Twitter profile should not be private.
Check the documentation at:
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default Twitter returns top 20 records.

What are you trying to do? If you are trying some library to query RSS feed, then I am sure that library will have option to specify that you wish to retrieve more than 20 records.

Comment: I am only using RSS link given on the bottom right corner of twitter page to fetch the rss feed and it's returning me only 20feeds

Answer (score 0):

A twitter's user RSS feed is limited to the last 20 tweets, as far as I know. I don't think there's any parameter you can pass to increase the count. If you want to fetch more tweets, you'd have to use [the API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com) rather than the RSS feed. Even that won't go back infinitely in history, though -- once you're over some set limit (though I can't remember what it is off-hand) there's no way of retrieving older tweets.